# Загрузка файла xls в django через браузер

Tags: django, fileupload, xls, openpyxl

Я загружаю файл test.xlsx через форму загрузки файлов в браузере и пытаюсь просмотреть его с помощью модуля Workbook.openpyxl в django.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook as XLSX_Workbook
....
filename = request.FILES['file'] # в переменной - test.xlsx
file_import = XLSX_Workbook.open_workbook(filename)
```

Когда я хардкожу полный путь к файлу, всё работает.
Проблема в том, что при загрузке браузер не показывает полный путь к файлу, а отображает его в виде C:\fakepath\test.xlsx, а чтобы открыть файл, нужно знать путь к нему. Как решить эту проблему?

---

РЕШЕНИЕ

Загрузим файл в память, не сохраняя его на сервере:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
```

Тогда считать его можно будет прямо из памяти:

```
filename = request.FILES['file']
file_import = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents = filename.read()) # для xls
```

Comment: В media файл появляется? Или он у вас в памяти висит и вы его не сохраняете?

Comment: @FeroxTL В media пусто. Я не знаю, как правильно делать, но мне нужно считывать данные. Получается, нужно указать, что файл сохраняется в MEDIA_ROOT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django обрабатывает файлы запроса с помощью upload handler-ов и возвращает список `request.FILES` список объектов класса [UploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/uploads/#uploaded-files) (или унаследованных классов). Надо или сохранить этот файл в хранилище и забрать его путь, или работать с объектами как есть, потому что они могут храниться как в памяти, так и в файловой системе.

Во втором случае должно сработать что-то вроде такого:

```
from io import BytesIO
from openpyxl import load_workbook

f = request.FILES['file']
file_import = load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(f.read()))
```

Comment: Спасибо, идея понятна. Добавила в вопрос своё решение на основе Вашего - считывать файл в память, а не сохранять его. До сих пор не совсем понятно, почему файл не загружается в определённую папку media, но конкретно моя проблема решена.

Comment: Файл не будет автоматически сохраняться в хранилище media, обычные формы такого не умеют. Это все надо вручную делать или использовать джанговскую модель и ModelForm.

Answer (score 1):

Базовая работа с файлами описана в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) -  вам в принципе интересен кусок, который позволяет работать с файлами

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

Вместо f.chunks() можно использовать f.read() если вы уверены, что файл в память поместится.

По Workbook бегло не смог найти документацию, но судя по методу ему таки нужен файл. Сохраните его на диск, а потом передайте в Workbook.open_workbook (видимо путь)

upd: вроде функция load_workbook для пути

Comment: Читать документацию - хорошо и правильно, но чтобы её понимать, надо писать программы, во время написания появляются вопросы, а в ответах отправляют читать документацию. Замкнутый круг =) Вопрос был не в том, как загрузить файл, а в том, как к нему обратиться. Кстати, загружаю я его с помощью js, не используя handle_uploaded_file. Наверное надо было указать это в вопросе.

Comment: @NewDevelop передайте файл, который у вас request.FILES['file'] в функцию handle_uploaded_file - он будет сохранён. Далее попробуйте поработать с тем путём, который там захардкожен - 'some/file/name.txt'. Если получится, тогда уже как-то модифицируйте своё приложение, чтобы путь был не статический. Ещё попробуйте отладчиком воспользоваться - pdb, например

Comment: Спасибо, я уже обновила вопрос, он решён. Когда закончу с текущей задачей, попробую разобраться в сохранении файлов подробнее.